# jQuery 1.7 "unifying bind/live/delegate"

Tags: jquery

The jQuery 1.7 release will "unify bind/live/delegate". What does this mean in term of the jQuery source? What are the consequences for my jQuery code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Corresponding ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9393)
- [Google Doc explaining the changes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vzJ_pl_bCKAisHu15DhTQkJBNGvgycW35lJW45d9P6U/edit?hl=en)

Short summary:

Currently we have three different event API pairs: bind/unbind, live/die, and delegate/undelegate. Since they all use the same event lists and events under the covers, exposing the APIs separately can lead to incorrect expectations. Introduction of jQuery.fn.on. Bind/Delegate/Live will stay as shorthand methods.

Comment: If I read that Google doc correctly, `$(selector).on(events, fn)` will have the same syntax as `$(selector).bind(events, fn)`, but will work for either existing objects or future objects as does `.live()` (kind of `.bind()` combined with `.live()`.  Is that correct?

Comment: No. `$(selector).on(events, fn)`has the same syntax as `$(selector).bind(events, fn)`, but only applies to current objects. To work on further objects use `$(document).on(events, selector, fn)` - Notice its document wide! If you're a little bit into pure JS: .on() attaches event handler(s) to $(elems). "selector" filters these elements. .live() is a document wide event listener (remember the event bubbling) checking whether objects match the given selectors and executing the corresponding callbacks if so.

Comment: OK.  I get it now.  That's architecturally a bit more consistent with how it actually works.  Wouldn't you expect that most coders would  stay with the shortcut versions of `$(selector).click(fn)` or `$(selector).live("click", fn)`?